# C# Cross threading. IRC stream thread to Main UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to get this little IRC program working but for some reason I'm having issues with VS and cross threading. I'm not sure if I'm not doing it the proper way or what. Here are the parts causing the issue.

Main Thread:

```
public partial class MainUI : Form 
{
    private static IRC irc = new IRC();
    public MainUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static void StartIRC()
    {
        irc.Start();
    }
}
```

IRC Thread:

```
class IRC 
{
    private Thread ircThread;
    private bool _running  = true;
    private NetworkStream stream;
    private StreamWriter writer;
    private StreamReader reader;
    private TcpClient irc;
    public IRC(){
        ircThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        ircThread.IsBackground = true;
    }
    public void Run(){
        while (_running) {
            parseInStream(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        ircThread.Start();
    }
    private void parseInStream(String inText)
    {
        String[] text = inText.Split(' ');
        String name;
        String message;
        if (text[1].Equals("PRIVMSG")) {
            name = capsFirstChar(getUser(inText));
            message = inText.Substring(inText.IndexOf(":", 1) + 1);
            sendToChatBox(capsFirstChar(name) + ": " + message, Color.Black);
        }
        else if (text[1].Equals("JOIN")) {
            name = getUser(inText);
            sendToChatBox(capsFirstChar(name) + " has joined the channel.", Color.LimeGreen);
        }
        else if (text[1].Equals("PART")) {
            name = getUser(inText);
            sendToChatBox(capsFirstChar(name) + " has left the channel.", Color.Red);
        }
    }
    public void sendToChatBox(String text, Color color)
    {       
        //Trying to send the text to the chatbox on the MainUI
        //Works if the MainUI.Designer.cs file has it set to static

        if (MainUI.txtMainChat.InvokeRequired) {
            MainUI.txtMainChat.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
                sendToChatBox(text, color);
            });
        }
        else {
            MainUI.txtMainChat.SelectionColor = color;
            MainUI.txtMainChat.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
    private String getUser(String msg)
    {
        String[] split = msg.Split('!');
        user = split[0].Substring(1);
        return capsFirstChar(user);
    }
    private String capsFirstChar(String text)
    {
        return char.ToUpper(text[0]) + text.Substring(1).ToLower();
    }
}
```

The only way I am able to get it to work is if I enter the MainUI.Designer.cs file and change the textbox to static and then change everything from this.txtMainChatto MainUI.txtMainChat.

My main problem is that when I make any changes on the visual side all the things labeled static or things named MainUI are deleted. I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to keep this from happening. Am I doing it the right way, or is there a better way? I tried using a background worker but it was using a lot of processing power to work that way for some reason.

I've looked around the web and can't seem to find out how one might relate to my setup. I see people calling a thread from the main thread and then sending things from the main thread to the thread it called but not the other way around. There is nothing else being written to the text box so there won't be an issue with it being used by two threads at the same time.

Comment: the code looks all ways too bundled together, which adds to the confusion. I would separate the code here into something like MVVM or at least change your UI and processing classes.
For example, you can have the IRC class read lines and invoke events, and then the MainForm code behind update itself (although imo that is still a poor choice, and it's best to introduce a ViewModel type of class).

What C# and .Net versions are you using? You may get better control if you are able to use TPL and async/await patterns (C#5/.Net 4.5 levels).

Comment: v4.5 on VS 2013. This is my first actual windows application so I know it's not in the best of form.

Answer (score 1):

Your designer file is rebuilt every time you change your UI in the designer.

You'll need to pass your MainUi to your IRC class, or give it an abstraction of it using an interface (best option).

```
public interface IMainUI
{
    void AddText(string text, Color color);
    void UiThread(Action code);
}

public class MainUI : IMainUI
{
     // Whatever else
    public void AddText(string text, Color color)
    {
        UiThread( () => 
        {
           // Same code that was in your Irc.SendToChatBox method.     
        });
    }

    public void UiThread(Action code)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(code);
            return;
        }
        code.Invoke();
    }
}

public class IRC
{
    IMainUI _mainUi;
    //Other properties, and fields    

    public IRC(IMainUI mainUi)
    {
        this._mainUi = mainUi;

        // Other constructor stuff.
    }

    // Other logic and methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On my main UI thread I passed in "this" so I could reference the main window from my IRC Class. MainUI.txtMainChat

```
irc = new IRC(this);
```

Then in my IRC class

```
MainUI main;
public IRC(MainUI main){
    this.main = main;
    ircThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
    ircThread.IsBackground = true;
}
```

Then I was able to Change

```
//MainUI.txtMainChat to
main.txtMainChat
```

Like Cameron said, Though I know I was told it's not the best approach it gets me started.